# Centering an image for responsive website

Tags: image, html, css, centering

So i am making a responsive design for a school assignment and i am trying to center an image width.

i scaled the image in photoshop so i don't have to set any width or height to the image

this is what i got now but this does not work

`<header>
     <img src="afb%20/logo3.png" alt="logo3" width="" height="" />
</header>`

`header{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
        }`

Can someone help me out ? really need this !

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `text-align: center` in the header CSS.

You are currently making the header 100% width, so your margins wont apply. Furthurmore since your container is 100% wide and there is no text-alignment, the img will ALWAYS be aligned on the left.

Here:

```
header { width: 100%; text-align: center; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xMPZ4/

Answer (score 3):

```
.center{margin: 0px auto; display: block;}

<header><img src="updates_button.jpg" alt="logo3" class="center"></header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a logo class to the image and set the CSS to : `margin:0px auto; width:200px;` of course replace the image width...